# Return to previous tensorflow version

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I have been running with tensorflow 2.3.0

A few days ago I tried installing a library with this

```
pip install tensorflow_decision_forests
```

This upgraded my tensorflow to 2.7.0 and now I'm having problems including not being able to use gpu in my training. Is there any way to revert this change?

I tried conda list --revisions but the last revision is from before this change.

Answer (score 1):

Runnig: pip install tensorflow==2.3.0

Solved my problem. Sorry for not trying it earlier but was afraid it would make it worse